# How to resize icon automatically upon adding new icon?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want your help regarding a problem.
I am creating an app, and I have like 9 images which I want to appear horizontally across the screen.
[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvwin.png)

But in the above screenshot, as you can see, I have only 8 images and the screen seems to be full, I want to add one more image of number 9. 
Here is my [activity_main.xml](https://hastebin.com/zularedeso.xml) (hastebin link)

It will be more helpful if you could explain to me a bit rather than just fixing it, also, could you please suggest other fixes, this is the college project I am working on. 
Thank you for your precious time :)

Answer (score 0):

If the images are fixed, you can set your LinearLayout width (the ones that contains the images) as "match_parent" and add the attribute weightSum = 9 . That will make its width the same as the container. Then you set each image width to 0 and add weight= 1.
This will make each image width 1/9 of the parent, no matter the size of the device screen.

It will look something like the answer of user9209780.